Loading from 'saved posts' on Instagram in Automation Project
I'm creating a little automation project that I hope to be used to help me be a little less lazy (ironic isn't it). With some background in Python, so I decided to make a randomizer that I use to load dance videos that I've saved while doom scrolling and I want to learn them. I've run into an issue.
Objective: Retrieve videos from a saved folder on Instagram
I'm using a library called 'instaloader' which is an API for Instagram which does some web scraping. I created a json file that would save information of a post in my saved folder: a link to the post, and a flag of whether the post has been completed. I randomly load the url from the the json afterwards to learn a post. I think I'm creating web dev levels that I'm beginning to get lost in.
Problem: The problem I have is accessing the posts from a specific folder on Instagram. The videos are in a folder named "Dance" and I can't figure out how I can access the posts using the instaloader library or any other methods I've that looked for. Idk if it's a library issue or I'm blind or I'm a dummy for using the wrong library. I've seen some suggestions about using the google web developer tools but I'm scared to touch it and have no idea where I would start
Has anyone ever tried something similar or the faintest idea of a solution?
Cheers.
CODE:
instaloader API git: https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader
import instaloader
import json
import os
import random

#Instaloader
L = instaloader.Instaloader()

username = 'notarealusername'
password = 'password123'
L.login(username, password)

profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, username)
#---------

#load json 
if os.path.exists('saved_posts.json'): 
    with open('saved_posts.json', 'r') as file:
        saved_posts = json.load(file)
else:       #create new
    saved_posts = []

#get saved posts
for saved_post in profile.get_saved_posts(): 
    if not any(post['id'] == saved_post.mediaid for post in saved_posts):
        saved_posts.append({                                                #json info
            'id': saved_post.mediaid,
            'url': f'https://www.instagram.com/p/{saved_post.shortcode}/', 
            'completed': False
        })

#save json
with open('saved_posts.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(saved_posts, file, indent=4)

#generate
def get_random_post(include_completed=False):
    with open('saved_posts.json', 'r') as file:
        saved_posts = json.load(file)
    
    if not include_completed:
        saved_posts = [post for post in saved_posts if not post['completed']]
    
    if not saved_posts:
        return None
    
    return random.choice(saved_posts)

#mark completed post
def mark_completed_post(post_url):
    with open('saved_posts.json', 'r') as file:
        saved_posts = json.load(file)
    
    for post in saved_posts:
        if post['url'] == post_url:
            post['completed'] = True
            break
    
    with open('saved_posts.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(saved_posts, file, indent=4)


def main():
    while True:
        print("1. Get a random dance post")
        print("2. Mark a post as completed")
        print("3. Exit")
        choice = input("Choose an option: ")

        if choice == '1':
            post = get_random_post()
            if post:
                print(f"Learn this dance: {post['url']}")
            else:
                print("No posts available.")
        elif choice == '2':
            post_url = input("Enter the post URL to mark as completed: ")
            mark_completed_post(post_url)
            print("Post marked as completed.")
        elif choice == '3':
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I was explored some other API's but this one was made the clearest sense to me given my skill. This is one of my first automation projects so I didn't know where else could advise on my issue
